# how to add an item to a listbox

Tags: excel, vba, userform

I have a set of data on a Userform in multiple textboxes.

I have written a code to find if there is a blank textbox left which would make the data sheet incomplete.

If the data is incomplete I want it to take my batch number (which is in `Txtbox10A10`) and put the batch number in my listbox so that I can access it later to complete the data.

Is there any way I can accomplish this? I have tried multiple ways with many errors.

Comment: Hello and welcome to SO. I'm afraid your question is too unclear to answer, you will have to be more specific (include your code and pinpoint where you go wrong). Please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), check [ask] a question with a [mcve] and edit your question accordingly =)

Comment: Scroll down this page and look at the list of questions in the bottom right of the page - they closely match your question. You may find something of value there.

Comment: You have to preserve batch values to a column when adding incomplete record set. Then use that column as listbox data source.

Comment: How did you load your listbox? And, please add your code to your question.

Comment: See [AddItem method](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/additem-method) and check examples at SO.

Answer (score 0):

hi sorry still new at vba

i have the following set of code

```
enter code here
```

``````
Dim i As Integer
Dim J As Integer
Dim uppercolJ As Integer
Dim Mistakes As Integer
Dim x As Integer
'    cmas = UserForm3.MultiPage1.Pages(UserForm3.MultiPage1.Value).Controls("Txtbox" & 1 & "A" & J)


Set Form = UserForm3.MultiPage1.Pages(UserForm3.MultiPage1.Value)
uppercolJ = 41
Mistakes = 0
        For J = 28 To uppercolJ
            ActiveTextBoxName = "Txtbox" & 1 & "A" & J

            If UserForm3.MultiPage1.Pages(3).Controls(ActiveTextBoxName) = "" Then
                Mistakes = Mistakes + 1

            Else


    End If
        Next J
         If Mistakes > 0 Then
  MsgBox "Cells are incomplete, saving for later completion"

Else
MsgBox "comp"
'Call save
End If
End Sub`````






now when Mistakes > 0 
then i would like it to save the batch no. of the product which can be found in Txtbox10A10
to a listbox i have created. so that if i come back tomorroww  to finish all my data i can call that information from the batch no. in my listbox,


i have all coding already done just not sure how to get it to add my backnumber to the listbox upon Mistakes > 0
``````

Comment: You probably want to rework your original question with this information.